# How to create docker image of pandas to AWS Lambda layers?

Tags: python, pandas, docker, aws-lambda

In order to use pandas library in AWS Lambda function, can we use docker image of required libraries in lambda function? If possible, how to deploy it?

Edited 4/11: Finally, I was able to create pandas docker container image and use it in AWS Lambda function. Please refer steps on my github: https://github.com/bkamalmca/AWSLambdaDocker

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: AWS Data Wrangler includes Pandas. AWS Data Wrangler Lambda layer is available in all AWS Commercial regions. https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Comment: Thanks, this was easy step to add wrangler layer then creating custom layer for pandas library.

Comment: I would also explore on creating docker images for Lambda not for pandas library (we got easy step) but for other purposes.